# UIView transitionFromView animate flip with different view sizes?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a small view and a big one, and want to flip animate between them, as a selection toggle (on a different button). I am using the UIView transition block method, and the flip is actually happening correctly.

However, during the transition, the larger view is cropped and cut down to the exact same size as the smaller one. On complete it again goes back to full size, but with a jerk. So while victory is so close, I've been playing with different permutations and combinations for the past 5 hours with no luck in smooth transition.

Is it really not possible to transition flip between 2 views of different sizes? Someone please help!

My one line transition is below. `ivCategory` is the small view, with `CGSize = (40.0f,48.0f)`. ivAvatar is the large view, with `CGSize = (124.0f,318.0f)`. Both are `UIImageView` views. Both already exist, added as subviews in the same parent view.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.ivCategory 
                    toView:self.ivAvatar
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight|UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: You may want this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429183/how-to-set-animation-to-uiimageview/8429276#8429276](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429183/how-to-set-animation-to-uiimageview/8429276#8429276) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the smaller view into a container view that's the same size as the larger view. The switch the larger view and the container view with your flip animation. You might be able to set opaque to NO and install a clear background color on the container view to get it to not show up at all. You'd have to test that on the lowest-end device you plan to support, though, since animating non-opaque views with transparency can be slow. (We're only supporting the 3Gs and above.)